# Maximize/Minimize external application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have got Skype configured to launch minimized on windows starts.

Now I need to bring Skype to front from a button from my full screen application button. I have got this code:

```
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcessesByName("skype")
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SHOW_WINDOW.SW_NORMAL)
    Next p
```

It works but, when I clicked the button my application is minimized and I need it to remain in this original state.

Any help?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9bde4870-1599-4958-9ab4-902fa98ba53a/

Comment: Thank you zenwalker, but it is not valid, because when I clicked the button, my full screen application goes minimized and I need to remain it maximized and the skype in front.

Comment: Nope, using the User32 API and playing with window handles, your main application wont go any where. I have done this once. I could minimize/close it to tray or what not. Noting would happen to main window. Trust me. Hope this solves http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/3336751/C-Tip-Placing-Your-C-Application-in-the-System-Tray.htm 

P.S: Dont forget 2 accept my answer if it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: it is not working... here is my code http://pastebin.com/LbXe4b19 and when I run this, my mainapp goes minimized, but skype is not maximized... and I need my Fullscreen app remains fullscreen...